# MQL4: OrderModifiy() return 130

Tags: mql4

`OrderModify` 130 returns to me on the backtest, but I have not found a way to fix it, what is it due to?

Log:

```
2021.09.14 16:27:56.485 2021.01.13 05:00:00  XXXX XAUUSD,H4: OrderModify error 130
2021.09.14 16:27:56.485 2021.01.13 05:00:00  XXX XAUUSD,H4: open #17 buy 1.17 XAUUSD at 1859.80 ok
2021.09.14 16:27:56.485 2021.01.13 05:00:00  XX XAUUSD,H4: lots:1.172578644923699,mod:0.01
2021.09.14 16:27:56.485 2021.01.13 05:00:00  XXXX XAUUSD,H4: lots:0.0,Last_Position_Size:1.160968955369999,Lot_Size_Mod:1.0
2021.09.14 16:27:56.485 2021.01.13 05:00:00  XXX XAUUSD,H4: BUY entry, Nearest_Up_Level:1855.3,Close[2]:1855.21,Close[1]:1859.73
```

```c#
void OpenTrade(string sym, int tmode, double tsize){
   int err = 0, ticket = 0;
   double TP = 0, SL = 0;
   
   if(!IsTradeAllowed()){
      while(true){
         if(IsTradeAllowed()) break;
         Sleep(100);
      } 
   }
   RefreshRates();
   
   if (tmode == OP_BUY){
      err = 1;
      while(err > 0){
         RefreshRates();
         
         //if (TakeProfit > 0) TP = Ask + TakeProfit * Point * mp;
         //else TP = 0;
         TP = BUY_TP_Price;
         //Print("Current TP distance:", (TP - Ask) / Point / mp);
         if ((TP - Ask) / Point / mp < Min_TP_Distance) TP = Next_BUY_TP_Price;

         if (Stop_Loss > 0) SL = Ask - Stop_Loss * Point * mp;
         else SL = 0;
         
         ticket = OrderSend(sym, OP_BUY, tsize, Ask, 0, 0, 0, "", Magic_Number, 0, Green);
         err = GetLastError();
        // Print(sym+" Buy open, err:",err);
        
         if (err == 3 || err == 64 || err == 65 || err == 130 || err == 131 || err == 133 || err == 134 || err == 148 || err == 4110 || err == 143 ) err = 0;
         
         if (err != 0) Sleep(1000);
      }
      
      if (ticket > 0 && (TP > 0 || SL > 0)){            
         if(OrderSelect(ticket,SELECT_BY_TICKET,MODE_TRADES)) 
            bool result = OrderModify(ticket, OrderOpenPrice(), SL*_Point, TP*_Point, 0, CLR_NONE);
      }
   }
   
   if (tmode == OP_SELL){
      err = 1;
      while(err > 0){
         RefreshRates();
         
         //if (TakeProfit > 0) TP = Bid - TakeProfit * Point * mp;
         //else TP = 0;
         TP = SELL_TP_Price;
         Print("Current TP distance:", (Bid - TP) / Point / mp, ",TP:",TP);
         if ((Bid - TP) / Point / mp < Min_TP_Distance) TP = Next_SELL_TP_Price;
         
         if (Stop_Loss > 0) SL = Bid + Stop_Loss * Point * mp;
         else SL = 0;
         
         ticket= OrderSend(sym, OP_SELL, tsize, Bid, 0, 0, 0, "", Magic_Number, 0, Red);
         err = GetLastError();
         //Print(sym+" Sell open, err:",err);
         if (err == 3 || err == 64 || err == 65 || err == 130 || err == 131 || err == 133 || err == 134 || err == 148 || err == 4111) err = 0;
         
         if (err != 0) Sleep(1000);
      }
      
      if (ticket > 0 && (TP > 0 || SL > 0)){            
         if(OrderSelect(ticket,SELECT_BY_TICKET,MODE_TRADES)) 
            bool result = OrderModify(ticket, OrderOpenPrice(), SL*_Point, TP*_Point, 0, CLR_NONE);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error code 130 is `ERR_INVALID_STOPS` (see [Error Codes](https://book.mql4.com/appendix/errors)).

This is specifically caused because you are using [OrderModify](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/ordermodify) incorrectly.

Stop Loss and Take Profit should be `Levels` not `Pips`. Modify your code to the following:

```
bool result;
if(OrderType()==OP_BUY) result=OrderModify(ticket, OrderOpenPrice(), NormalizeDouble(OrderOpenPrice()-SL*_Point, Digits), NormalizeDouble(OrderOpenPrice()+TP*_Point, Digits), 0, CLR_NONE);
else result=OrderModify(ticket, OrderOpenPrice(), NormalizeDouble(OrderOpenPrice()+SL*_Point, Digits), NormalizeDouble(OrderOpenPrice()-TP*_Point, Digits), 0, CLR_NONE);
```

It is good practice to Normalise your levels to `Digits` also which I have included in the code above.

Comment: Your lot sizes are also incorrect. You need to adjust your lot size for the broker specification which you can find using [MarketInfo()](https://docs.mql4.com/marketinformation/marketinfo) and `MODE_MINLOT`, `MODE_LOTSTEP` and `MODE_MAXLOT`